# VS Code adding an extra "}" on save of a liquid file

Tags: visual-studio-code, liquid

In VS Code if I save my liquid file every time it adds an extra "}" on the end. I have disabled all other extensions.

Basically, my code looks like this in the end:

```
{% schema  %}
    {}
{% endschema %}}}}}}}}}
```

My settings are as follows for user:

```
{
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
"FIG_NEW_SESSION": "1"
},
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnType": true,
"editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
"[liquid]": {
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.defaultFormatter": "sissel.shopify-liquid",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"liquid.format.enable": true
},
"liquid.format.enable": true,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"explorer.confirmDelete": false,
"files.associations": {
"*.liquid": "liquid"
},
"workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula Soft"
}
```

and workspace:

```
{
"liquid.format.enable": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnType": true,
"editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
"[liquid]": {
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.defaultFormatter": "sissel.shopify-liquid",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"liquid.format.enable": true
},
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"explorer.confirmDelete": false,
"files.associations": {
"*.liquid": "liquid"
}
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to find an answer?

Comment: See here this worked...
https://github.com/panoply/vscode-liquid/issues/111

Answer (score 0):

In settings.json file, include the following:

```
"[liquid]": {
   "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was addressed in the latest release of the extension. See https://github.com/panoply/vscode-liquid/issues/120